# Header breaks in Internet Explorer

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

Just opened Travel StackExchange in Internet Explorer ( IE 8 ).

The header breaks. It does not display the Tags / Users/Badges and Unanswered.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Repro on IE8/WinXP. However, IE8 is not among the browsers supported by Stack Exchange team: see this [supported browsers question on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/150290).

In short, I wouldn't keep my hopes up to have this fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Mindcorrosive is correct, we no longer support IE8.